# Office.js recognizing ContentControl positions in the document

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am not sure this is doable out of the box, but this is what I have:

- document with multiple ContentControls
- all of them have the same tag by which they can be found and worked on

No issues there. However, is there a way to know, using something inside Office.js, if two or more ContentControls are next to each other inside the document? By 'next to each other' I mean: no other text, objects etc. in between them. I am asking because I'm attempting to merge such ContentControls. That is not an issue, but recognizing them might be.

Is this possible through Office.js or do I need to write my own custom logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built into the Word object models that will tell you this. But you can calculate it from the `Range` of the content controls using the `compareLocationWith` method. For example: the following snippet compares the location of the first and second content controls in a document. If the first is immediately before the second the method returns `AdjacentBefore`, otherwise it will return `Before`.

```
    var ccs = context.document.body.contentControls;
    ccs.load("items");
    await context.sync();
    var nrCCs = ccs.items.length;

    if (nrCCs >= 2) {   
      var cc1 = ccs.items[0];
      var cc2 = ccs.items[1];
      var rng1 = cc1.getRange("Whole");
      var rng2 = cc2.getRange("Whole");
      var sCompareResult = rng1.compareLocationWith(rng2);
      await context.sync();
      console.log(sCompareResult.value);
    }
```

Comment: When using compareLocationWith on two copies of the same range, it doesn't seem to return Equal.  It returns either Inside or InsideEnd.  Is that expected behavior?